# IBM Content Navigator: Difference between NonServiceLogger and ServiceLogger

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I see there are 2 logging classes mainly used in ICN plugin customization, viz. NonServiceLogger and ServiceLogger. Does anybody know the difference between them? I checked the documentation of the classes in help portal, but that's not clear enough. What would be the ideal scenario to use them individually?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug in can be used to create a service functionality  or any other functionality. The logger are specifically differentiated according to that.

Service plugin - like calling a service in fuse to validate the data entered by the user. The servicelogger is preferred here as compared to non service one. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEUEX_3.0.5/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/eucso006.htm

nonservice plugin is used when no service is being called via the plugin.

The difference is nominal but when you use the nonservice logger in service plugin.. the logs are generated in a temp folder(not known location) which will increase the size of that drive and it will not be cleared off (like if service logger is used). This is what we faced recently and have to change the logger to service one..

thanks ..